# How to implement computable observables in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want add some methods. And `this` directive can't help me.

```
var viewModel = function () {
    firstName = ko.observable("Mike");
    lastName = ko.observable("Rassel")
    //fullName = ko.computed(function () { 
         //return firstName() + " " + lastName(); }, viewModel);
}

viewModel.fullName = ko.computed(function () { 
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(); }, viewModel);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gJUqK/

On local with 2.1.0 its work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `firstName`, `lastName` and `fullName` should be properties of the `myViewModel` instance.

This will work, as explained in [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). The `self` is added, because inside the `fullName` observable callback function `this` would point to something else.

```
function myViewModel()
{
    var self = this;

    this.firstName = ko.observable("Mike");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Rassel");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName();
    })
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gJUqK/1/

Comment: @FreeVice what is not outside? I'm not following.

Comment: sorry, someone edidted my question to unrecognizable

Comment: @FreeVice yes, I edited the title to make it more searchable; you can see from the "Related" column on the right that the subject lines match your topic better.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that, with the way that you are calling `viewModel`, `this` is bound to the global object for the `fullName` function.

You can start to correct this by making `viewModel` a constructor and adding `fullName` to its prototype:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
  this.firstName = "Mike";
  this.lastName = "Rassel";
}

ViewModel.prototype.fullName = function () { 
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; 
};

var view = new ViewModel(); // Call ViewModel with new
console.log(view.fullName()); // Prints "Mike Rassel"
```

I don't understand the knockout stuff, but hopefully this should get you closer to a solution.

Comment: Your proposal will help. Hovewer prototype is not usual stuff for solving such issues. Main reason - referrencing functions from View and this might be lost. `var self = this;` and using `self` instead of `this` is more common solution

Comment: @Romanych I assume you are referring to a pattern similar to @Jack's answer, which I agree is fairly common place.  One advantage to the prototype route is that IF `fullName` is a function and not the output of a function (I say "if" because I am not sure exactly what knockout.js is doing here) then adding it to the prototype reduces memory usage, since all instances of `ViewModel` will share the single declaration.  Defining it within the object itself and using `self` to refer back to the object means that each instance has its own `fullName` definition.

Comment: fullName has to be a `ko.computed` for the bindings to work, and it tracks dependent properties among other things.